# flask does not see change in .js file

Tags: python, flask, flask-cache

I made a change on one of the `.js` files that I use and no matter what I do, flask insists on picking up, from memory cache, the last version of the file, without the change.

To clarify, I have the following structure. It all starts with `foo.html`

```
return render_template foo.html
```

`foo.html` has a form inside that  calls flask with some data and then returns a second template `bar.html`:

```
return render_template bar.html
```

This second template calls some `.js` file, placed in the `static` folder, but it doesn't update when the code changes.

I mention the structure above because if the `.js` file was placed on `foo.html` instead of `bar.html` then Flask **would** pick up the new changes on the file. But in `bar.html` Flask completely ignores them.

What is happening?

The only thing that worked was to click on "disable cache" on the browser and reload again.

Comment: If you're able to make a change in the browser to make a JS file show up, then the problem probably isn't on the server.

Comment: it is not problem with flask but browser keeps old version in cache to work faster. Normally you will work with static .js and it makes no problem. Some servers use dynamic urls for scripts to force browser to load new version - ie. `"script.js?some_variable=dynamic_value"` . `dynamic_value` can be version number or date of file.

Comment: but how can I make the browser not use the cached version? Also, why does the second case work fine then?

Comment: A good way to work around this type of browser cache issue is to include version numbers in your static js files... e.g. instead of `custom.js` use `custom.1.2.js`

Comment: I'm in the process of development though, I'm constantly changing the `.js` file, surely one cannot be expected to rename the files with every single change.

Comment: Yes, I just do hard refreshes in dev. On Mac in Chrome this is CMD-R

Comment: if `Ctrl+F5` or `Ctrl+R` doesn't work then disable cache in browser till you create final version or use `"script.js?some_variable=file_timestamp"` and add create function to generat url with parameter.

Comment: so Ctrl+R does not work but cmnd + R does work, on mac at least. @PJSantoro, if you want to post as a solution I'll accept.

Comment: You can also disable cache, this will solve the issue. On chrome, press ctrl+shift+I then go to Network, then at the top, check the box that says "disable cache"

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Ultimately this is a frustrating browser cache issue, which can be solved by forcing the browser to do a "hard refresh", which is going to be a browser/OS dependent keystroke, but generally this works:

- Windows: Ctrl+F5
- Mac: Cmd+Shift+R
- Linux: Ctrl+Shift+R

There are other filename tricks one can use to avoid this issue (mentioned in comments of the OP). These are especially important in production where you have no control over browser behavior.

For non-Static Flask responses you can set the `cache_control.max_age` property, which should tell the browser when to expire the response if it is cached. For instance if you have a Flask XHR endpoint that returns JSON data you could do this:

```
@app.route('/_get_ajax_data/')
def get_ajax_data():
    data = {"hello": "world"}
    response = jsonify(data)
    response.cache_control.max_age = 60 * 60 * 24  # 1 day (in seconds)
    return response
```

You typically can also set default values in your production web server configuration for specific resource types (e.g. CSS/JS/HTML/JSON/etc)

**Edit 4/1/2019** (unrelated to April Fools day)

- Mac / Safari keystroke now appears to be: Cmd+Opt+R (via comments, thanks!).
- See the new answer from @MarredCheese for a very elegant "filename trick" to force the browser to ignore cached copies for updated files.

Comment: Mac change on 2019
• Cmd+Opt+R

Comment: thanks @CarlosGaleano . . . this seems to be specific to Safari from what I can tell, but added an edit here to mention this.

Comment: They get April Fools as early as January in the US. 

Answer (score 42):

Caching is *normally good*, so it's not advisable to eliminate it entirely.  And using <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> or whatever to do a hard refresh is obviously not a scalable solution since you have to do it in every browser on every computer.

A better idea is to **let browsers cache the files most of the time, but not right after they've been updated.**  You can achieve this by appending the time that the source file was last updated as an argument to its path URL.  For simplicity, you can use the most recent modification time for any file in the static folder (or any subfolders), as opposed to looking at each file individually.

### Python

```
def dir_last_updated(folder):
    return str(max(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root_path, f))
                   for root_path, dirs, files in os.walk(folder)
                   for f in files))

@app.route('/my-site')
def my_site():
    return render_template('my-site.html',
                           last_updated=dir_last_updated('mydir/static'))
```

### Jinja Template

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/my-script.js?u={{ last_updated }}"></script>
```

### HTML Result

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/my-script.js?u=1547330602.31"></script>
```

Comment: This is the best answer for websites in production where users have a cached version of the files.

Answer (score 25):

If you are serving your static assets with Flask (this is typically the case in a development environment), then you might need to set the [`SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT` configuration value](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT):

> Default cache control max age to use with `send_static_file()` (the default static file handler) and `send_file()`, as `datetime.timedelta` or as seconds. Override this value on a per-file basis using the `get_send_file_max_age()` hook on Flask or Blueprint, respectively. Defaults to 43200 (12 hours).

Solving this can be as simple as updating the `app.config` dictionary, like so:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
...
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0
```

If you do that, your browser will not cache static assets that are served by Flask.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
    app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0
    app.run(debug=True)
```

You can update using `F5` or `CTRL + R`.

Answer (score -3):

USE CTRL+ f5 to refresh the browser