# Dynamic json data in a file is not getting changed in flask python webpage

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have webpage which is rendered using Flask python. In that page I am using a json file whose data will change according to the search criteria. I put the json file in a static folder. Issue is, the json data change is not getting reflected in the browser.

```
d3.json("{{ url_for( 'static', filename='data/Emails_export_sql.json') }}", function(graph) {
force
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)   
  .start();
}
```

I tried saving the json file in folders other than 'static' folder. But it will not work. Where do I need to save the json file?

Comment: Could try adding a `<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />` to your html headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is a browser cache issue.

There is some discussion of it here: [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144565/flask-does-not-see-change-in-js-file/41146588#41146588). Essentially the issue here is that you're requesting the same URL over and over again so the default behavior is to cache the response.

### Recommendation

Use Flask's [**send_from_directory()**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_from_directory)    function instead of the static file fetch... e.g.:

```
from Flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/get_file/')
def get_file():
    # cache_timeout is in seconds from the send_file options
    return send_from_directory("data", "xyz.json", cache_timeout=5)
```

This will set the response headers to indicate to the browser that cache should expire in 5 seconds.

Another way to short circuit the browser cache for this resource (assuming you always want a *new* response) is to append a timestamp to the end of the URL:

```
// note... this timestamp approach fails on <IE9
var timestamp = Date.now(),
    base_url = "{{ url_for("get_file") }}",
    add_timestamp = base_url + "?t=" + timestamp;

d3.json(add_timestamp, function(graph) {
    force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)   
      .start();
}
```

In your serverside script you can just ignore the timestamp argument, but it should reliably short circuit the browser side of any cache issues.

Comment: what is 'url' here? -->  d3.json(url, function(graph) {<-- is it add_timestamp?

Comment: Thanks Santoro. I tried the last option you have given ant it worked...